# Hosting Multiple Static Web Apps on Azure using common custom domain name

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-web-app-routing

I have 3 to 5 direct static web apps (not storage account static web apps) that I have hosted them on Azure with custom domain name as below. for now all working fine,

[www.app1.com](http://www.app1.com/)
[www.app2.com](http://www.app2.com/)
[www.app3.com](http://www.app3.com/)

i will be creating common domain name [www.testing.com](http://www.testing.com/) across all apps.

i need to tag all the above static web apps to this common domain name and should able to browse like below,

[www.testing.com/app1](http://www.testing.com/app1)
[www.testing.com/app2](http://www.testing.com/app2)
[www.testing.com/app3](http://www.testing.com/app3) etc.

This will prevent cross-domain requests and sharing of local/session storage across all photon apps.

How can i achieve this in azure?

I have tried using Azure front door but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Is `www.testing.com` an Azure App Service  or a Static Web App ?

Comment: It has to work with Azure Front door.What are the issues you are facing with Azure Front Door ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this scenario in Azure front door, you can make use of below workaround:

I used a web app as I don't have a custom domain in a static web app. You can follow the same steps as below:

In web App -> configuration in path mapping I added path /`app1` same for all apps

[image]

In static web app -> Edit workflow -> `staticwebapp.config.json` add your path `/app1` same for other apps. Check this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration)

In Azure front door add origin group like below:

[image]

Update route like below:

[image]

[image]

when I redirect with front door with app1 and app2 it redirected successfully like below:

[image]

So, if you want to access `www.testing.com/`in Azure front door in routes you have to add app1, app2, app3 as three routes with origins. Then app1 should go to application1 same for all also static apps make sure to edit workflow and add your path for all apps.

if I get a request on this with `/app1`, it should forward that request to default Origin group like [this](https://i.imgur.com/6PSvFYy.png) Default Origin group is my app1 like [this](https://i.imgur.com/VMyTlw8.png) if `/app1` should need to access make sure  `/app1`also available in your web app (path mapping).

***Reference***:

[Azure front Door routing rule not working throws error "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/588983/azure-front-door-routing-rule-not-working-throws-e) by GitaraniSharma

Comment: Hi @Imran
Thanks for your answer, I will do as per your answer.

Comment: @Developer is your issue is resolved?